# Wordpress site not working in Safari

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

In the last couple of weeks I've noticed that wordpress is no longer working in Safari, on iPhones or iPad. It works in every other browser though. There have been no new plugins installed, although some updates to wordpress itself. I have tried disabling all plugins (theres only akismet, facebook and hubspot), but no luck.

The blog home page does not load at all on iPhone or iPad safari browsers and instead goes to a site index file.

On a mac, safari will open the blog homepage alright (index.php) however whenever I try to open a particular post, the url is prepended with:

```
"feed:"
eg feed:www.mydomain.com/blog/post-title
```

This causes safari on a device to try to open the link as a podcast, and on a mac as an RSS feed (I think).

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

I also thought maybe it was something to do with my htaccess file, but again, this hasn't changed - here it is though:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Note, my main site is not wordpress - wordpress is only installed as a blog in the mydomain.com/blog file.

EDIT:
I've tried resetting my theme back to a standard wordpress theme (2014) and I'm still getting the error - every blog post I try to open in safari gets prepended with 'feed:' and safari attempts to open it as an RSS feed. I've reset back to my custom theme (which is a child of 2014 anyway).

Here's an example from the Blog: https://www.loylap.com/blog/loylap-built-by-millennials-designed-for-everybody/  None of the actual post pages work, but the home page is fine.

Comment: What's the URL so we can see it happen and help debug?

Comment: First i would try to open wp-login.php if it works maybe your theme is buggy, Second switch back to one of the default themes

Comment: This sounds like an issue with the theme or a RSS Plugin. Does this happen on all your test devices? What User-Agent is being set when you run Safari? This is a developer mode item. Check your `access.log` file. Also look at the page with "View Source" and see if the links are being pre-pended with `feed:`

Comment: Thanks - I added a few more details above. @Twisty - The links in the web page seem fine which makes me think its something the browser is receiving an interpreting wrong rather than me sending up incorrectly. I had a look at the access log and this is an example of what it spits out when I click a link: "GET /blog/safeguard-your-customer-loyalty-success-with-loylap/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1467 "http://www.loylap.com/blog/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/600.8.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.8 Safari/600.8.9"

Comment: Back from vacation. This looks like a setting issue. When I view the link you provided, I get an XML Feed: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rss version="2.0"
 xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
 xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
 xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
 xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
 xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
 xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
 >`